# Merge and Make A Blank Space

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've a table that has three rows under weight allowance column at the footer. As you can see it has the three rows as follows:

```
Weight 1    20
Weight 2    40
Weight 4    60
```

What I am trying to make that area blank and something as this one: [Sample Output](https://ibb.co/yhv4K03)

I tried to play around and used colspan or rowspan to make the tweak but seems am unable to do it. Is there any proper workaround for this?

```css
.table th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Discipline</td>
      <th colspan="3">Weight Type 1</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Weight Percentage (%)</th>
      <th colspan="3">Weight Type 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Weight 1</th>
      <th>Weight 2</th>
      <th>Weight 4</th>
      <th>Weight 1</th>
      <th>Weight 2</th>
      <th>Weight 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <th>Discipline 1</th>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td colspan="2">100</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <th>Discipline 2</th>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td colspan="2">100</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <b>Summation</b>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">30</td>
      <td rowspan="3">60</td>
      <td rowspan="3">90</td>
      <td style="width: 100px;">Weight 1</td>
      <td style="width: 100px;">20</td>
      <td rowspan="3">6</td>
      <td rowspan="3">3</td>
      <td rowspan="3">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Weight 2</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Weight 4</td>
      <td>60</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `rowspan="3" and` colspan="2"` on that new empty cell:

```css
.table th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Discipline</td>
      <th colspan="3">Weight Type 1</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Weight Percentage (%)</th>
      <th colspan="3">Weight Type 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Weight 1</th>
      <th>Weight 2</th>
      <th>Weight 4</th>
      <th>Weight 1</th>
      <th>Weight 2</th>
      <th>Weight 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <th>Discipline 1</th>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td colspan="2">100</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <th>Discipline 2</th>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td colspan="2">100</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <b>Summation</b>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">30</td>
      <td rowspan="3">60</td>
      <td rowspan="3">90</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="2"></td>
      <td rowspan="3">6</td>
      <td rowspan="3">3</td>
      <td rowspan="3">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

However, now every cell in the bottom row has `rowspan="3"`, so you might want to remove all the `rowspan`s from the bottom row.